# Christoffel symbols as the expansion coefficients of covariant/contravariant derivatives

Tags: riemannian-geometry, books, tensor

Page 155 of [Vector and Tensor Analysis with Applications](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CRIjIx2ac6AC), by A.I Borishenko and I.E. Tarapov, the authors state that Christoffel symbols of the *second* kind are expansions of $\frac{\partial {\bf e}_j}{\partial x_k}$ with respect to the basis ${\bf e}_1 , {\bf e}_2 , {\bf e}_3$, whereas Christoffel symbols of the *first* kind are expansions of $\frac{\partial {\bf e}_j}{\partial x_k}$ with respect to the basis ${\bf e}^1 , {\bf e}^2 , {\bf e}^3$. Yet **different** derivatives subsequently appear in the arguments that follow, as shown below.

[image]

---

[image]
[image]

Would someone kindly shed a light on what's going on here?

*This question was originally posted on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829173/proof-of-expression-for-christoffel-symbols-of-the-first-kind-i-j-k-bf) but I wasn't able to find any help. Also, I am self-taught and not a mathematician.*

Comment: I'd say there's definitely a typo on the lhs of (5.10), and the usage of "expansion coefficients" is a bit surprising, but consistent if we fix the aforementioned typo.

Comment: Agreed, all cases of $\partial {\bf x}_k$ must be a typo, and should be $\partial {\bf x}^k$. That aside, have you got an inkling of how (5.9) and (5.10) imply (5.11)?

Comment: I don't see why one would need (5.9) - I would have just multiplied (the corrected) (5.10) by ${\bf e}_{l} $ and used ${\bf e}^{i} \cdot {\bf e}_{l} = \delta^{i}_{l} $, unless this book doesn't define the dual basis by the latter relation (which would also be very surprising).

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt I thought so too but how does one get $g_{il}$ from $\delta_l^i$? -- see equation (5.12)

Comment: For the first equation, take the dot product of (5.9) with $e_i$. For the second, take the dot product of (5.10) with $e^i$.

Comment: @DeaneYang Many thanks! Can you confirm that (5.11) follows from (5.10) and the recovery theorem.

Comment: Not sure what the recovery theorem is. It follows from the fact that $e_i\cdot e^j = 1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @DeaneYang That's what I meant. If you care to, please post an answer and I will mark it as such.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit reluctant to, since I'm just adding details @MichaelEngelhardt's correct answer. So I'll let him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a hat tip to Deane Yang, who supplied half of the discussion in the comments to the OP, the conclusion is:

- The three instances of $\partial / \partial x_k $ in the displayed book excerpt are typos and should read $\partial / \partial x^k $.
- (5.11) follows from (5.10) by taking the dot product with ${\bf e}_{l} $,
  $$
  {\bf e}_{l} \cdot \frac{\partial {\bf e}_{j} }{\partial x^k } = [ij,k] \ {\bf e}_{l} \cdot {\bf e}^{i} = [ij,k] \ \delta_{l}^{i} = [lj,k]
  $$
- (5.12) (left) follows from (5.9) by taking the dot product with ${\bf e}_{l} $, and invoking (5.11),
  $$
  [lj,k] = {\bf e}_{l} \cdot \frac{\partial {\bf e}_{j} }{\partial x^k } = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} i \\ j \ \ \ k\end{array} \right\} {\bf e}_{l} \cdot {\bf e}_{i} = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} i \\ j \ \ \ k\end{array} \right\} g_{li}
  $$
- (5.12) (right) follows from (5.10) by taking the dot product with ${\bf e}^{l} $, and invoking the definition (5.7),
  $$
  \left\{ \begin{array}{c} l \\ j \ \ \ k\end{array} \right\} =
  {\bf e}^{l} \cdot \frac{\partial {\bf e}_{j} }{\partial x^k } = [ij,k] \ {\bf e}^{l} \cdot {\bf e}^{i} = [ij,k] g^{li}
  $$